# Error building angular2 library

Tags: node.js, angular, build

This is my tsconfig-build.json used for taking the build

`{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "es2015",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "outDir": "../dist"
    },
    "files": ["./index.ts"],
    "angularCompilerOptions": {
        "genDir": "compiled",
        "strictMetadataEmit": true,
        "skipTemplateCodegen": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "dist",
        "gh-pages",
        "**/*.ngfactory.ts",
        "**/*.shim.ts",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}`

this is the script in my package.json file

`"scripts": {
        "prebuild": "rimraf ./dist ./compiled",
        "build": "ngc -p ./src/tsconfig-build.json"
    },`

While running the script `npm run build` , Im getting missing error listed below.

`../node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_provider.d.ts(87,123): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
../node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_provider.d.ts(87,165): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
../node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(58,60): error TS2693: 'Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
../node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(73,59): error TS2693: 'Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
../node_modules/@angular/core/src/change_detection/differs/iterable_differs.d.ts(14,48): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Iterable'.
../node_modules/@angular/core/src/change_detection/differs/keyvalue_differs.d.ts(22,18): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
../node_modules/@angular/core/src/change_detection/differs/default_iterable_differ.d.ts(12,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Iterable'.../node_modules/@angular/core/src/change_detection/differs/default_keyvalue_differ.d.ts(24,16): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
../node_modules/@angular/core/src/change_detection/differs/default_keyvalue_differ.d.ts(32,16): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
../node_modules/@angular/common/src/directives/ng_class.d.ts(48,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
../node_modules/ionic-angular/util/module-loader.d.ts(13,14): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
../node_modules/ionic-angular/util/module-loader.d.ts(14,18): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
../node_modules/ionic-angular/util/base-input.d.ts(2,38): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/forms'.
../node_modules/ionic-angular/util/base-input.d.ts(3,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/forms'.
../node_modules/ionic-angular/components/datetime/datetime.d.ts(2,38): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/forms'.
../node_modules/ionic-angular/components/input/input.d.ts(2,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/forms'.
../node_modules/ionic-angular/components/range/range.d.ts(2,38): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/forms'.
../node_modules/ionic-angular/components/searchbar/searchbar.d.ts(2,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/forms'.
../node_modules/ionic-angular/components/segment/segment.d.ts(2,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/forms'.
../node_modules/ionic-angular/gestures/gesture-config.d.ts(1,37): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser'.`

> Its a simple angular directive for ionic app,What might be the reason
>   for above missing statements ?

#### Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your **`tsconfig.json`** as

```
 "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es5", "es6", "dom"],  <--- this
    ...
  }
```